# Sharepoint List Validation (Only alphabets allowed)

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, sharepoint-online, calculated-columns

#Only Alphabets validation in text column of sharepoint online

I am trying to set validation to allow only alphabets in Column name " Visitor Full Name".
I need a formula which should be lengthy because list validation have a limit of 1024 char and i have to include other formulas as well.
I have tried below formulas but no result:

=IF(ISERROR(FIND(LOWER([Visitor Full Name]), "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")), TRUE, FALSE)
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$", [Visitor Full Name])), FALSE, TRUE)
=IF(REGEX([Visitor Full Name], "^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$"), TRUE, "Special characters are not allowed.")
=AND(IF(ISERROR(FIND(REGEX("[^a-zA-Z0-9]",[Visitor Full Name]))),TRUE,FALSE))
=IF(ISERROR(FIND(REGEX("[^a-zA-Z0-9]",ColumnName))),TRUE,FALSE)

below one is working but i need shorten length formula
=AND(IF(ISERROR(FIND("0",Title)),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("1",Title)),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("2",Title)),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("3",Title)),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("4",Title)),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("5",Title)),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("6",Title)),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("7",Title)),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("8",Title)),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("9",Title)),TRUE)

Thank you in advanced for your help..

Comment: Hi, please format your code. Read [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).Thank you